# Magnolia 5.5.6 Stories App Custom CKEditor Panel

Tags: ckeditor, magnolia

The Magnolia-Team wrote [(DevelopingCustomBlocks)](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Developing+and+rendering+custom+content+blocks) that the RichTextFieldDefinition is not available for Blocks.

I would love to use content-editor in the future instead of pages. Is it possible to extent the editor panel
[image: Editor-Panel] 
with (custom) plugins for the ckeditor (that I created to use with the RichTextField)? If yes could you give me a hint on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, and you can even use the standard `RichTextField`. 
However before you start extending it, please make sure you understand idea behind new editor, it's working, structure of data it stores and how is that data manipulated later in order to not dig for yourself hole that would be hard to escape with custom extensions.

Whole editor is meant to be fluent for editing and very simple to manipulate offering maximum of freedom. Editor works with concept of blocks. Each hit of enter produces new block of type text. There's other types of blocks offered OOTB by Magnolia. Each different type of block is stored separately and it's rendering can be controlled by template. E.g. each text block becomes paragraph or div in html, depending on your choice. For other blocks, they might produce other types of elements. And this is where you need to become careful. If you extend CK editor, or start using default/old `RichTextField`, you will suddenly end up with block that already contains html, thus making it unpredictable what the output might look like after such block is processed by your template and whether resulting html is valid or well formatted. The less of html you get "baked in" in each block, the easier templating becomes later.

As for adding extra plugins to the text block, you can modify `config.js` of the editor, as for adding `RichTextField` you can just create block that will provide this field. However, keep in mind that with first you run into risk of introducing potentially dangerous html and with the second it's same risk of baking in dangerous html and on top breaking editor experience as RTF will not support same keyboard shortcuts available for other blocks.